# How do I use fgets() to pull a line of text out from a file?

Tags: c, file, fgets

I'm writing a program that has to pull one line of text from a file and check if the letter C is in said line. I'm trying to use fgets() to pull the text I need from the line, but have so far been completely unable to produce any output.

Here is the code I've tried:

```
fgets(char 1, int maxlen, FILE input_file)
```

The input file it's pulling from is called `input_file` and the text within is formatted as follows:

```
25,F
32,F
-40,C
-20,C
-20,F
-40,F
0,C
```

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

Comment: The code you've written is not valid C.

Comment: `char buf[100]; if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) != NULL) {`

Answer (score 1):

For a function call, code needs to pass values, not variable declarations.

Be sure to check the result of `fgets()` and any parsing performed.

```
FILE *ifile;
// add code to open file
char buf[100];

// fgets(char 1, int maxlen, FILE input_file)
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, ifile) != NULL) { 
  int temp;
  char scale;
  if (2 != sscanf(buf, "%d , %c", &temp, &scale) {
    // Oops, bad input
    break;
  }

  // Do something with data
  printf("Temperature %d degrees %c\n", temp,scale);
}

// code to close file
```